# Has American Samoa in fact banned citizens of Russia from entry?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, russian-citizens, samoa, american-samoa

There is [a report](http://varlamov.ru/2275311.html) that a controversial Russian photographer has been denied American Samoa visa, because " the American Samoa Immigration Office has a travel ban in effect that now includes travelers holding a Russia passport".

I was not able to find any information regarding such ban on [official American Samoa immigration site](https://www.americansamoa.gov/immigration-info), no [anywhere online](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=america%20samoa%20bans%20visitors%20holding%20russian%20passport).

Can somebody independently confirm the existence or absence of such a ban? Or is it just another propaganda episode.

Comment: I think the guy is either a liar or his travel agent is an idiot.

Comment: @JonathanReez, I tend to agree, but given recent US immigration bans everything is possible. Just checking.
Note a grammar error in his quote from the reply from some "migration office".

Comment: A simple email to the Samoa immigration office should clear things up.

Comment: But there is no e-mail address. Only phone. And very uncomfortable time zone

Comment: email address for Attorney General's Office - okboard.asag@gmail.com

Comment: And the time zone is not too bad - you can call at 10PM European time and reach them at 10AM local time.

Comment: And please note that it is Samoans who govern and who are the officials that review and grant visas. So, if he was refused, Samoans made that decision.

Comment: TIMATIC says a visa is required, no suggestion that entry will be refused.

Comment: The story, at least as seen through Google Translate, makes no sense, since American Samoa operates its own immigration system. I doubt the current US President has even heard of the place. Whatever happened, if something happened, is unclear, but that article has clear inconsistencies.

Comment: It’s too late to migrate now, but I think Skeptics.SE may have been a better fit, as it doesn’t seem to be addressing a real problem but is instead checking the veracity of a claim.

Comment: There was a follow-up [here](https://varlamov.ru/2292619.html). There Mr. Varlamov wrote: _Do you remember I told you that [Russian citizens are banned from visiting American Samoa](https://varlamov.ru/2275311.html)?_ Then he tells that he contacted Russian MFA on this, MFA allegedly requested Samoans, after which he got excuses and a promise to issue him a visa if he reapplies. However, when he did so, he allegedly got refused again and the explanation was the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

American Samoa, Motu O Fiafiaga, has an independent government and, as such, its own visa policy. For example, a US visa or ESTA cannot be used to enter nor can a visa be obtained through any US embassy or consulate, but only through direct application to Attorney General's Office in American Samoa.

There is no evidence that the Government of American Samoa has made any such pronouncement regarding Russian nationals. It suggests that the individual has made an unsubstantiated and spurious claim. The American Samoa goverment has the right to deny visa applications, as it sees fit.

> Under the auspices of the [Department of Legal Affairs (Attorney General's Office)](https://www.americansamoa.gov/immigration-info) the Immigration Office enforces the lawful entrance into the Territory of American Samoa. They are tasked with protecting the borders and regulating travel to and from the Territory. **American Samoa is the only United States Territory that has retained oversight of its own borders.**  Immigration officers are stationed at all ports to ensure all travelers entering American Samoa have proper travel documents. The main office is located on the first floor of the A.P. Lutali Executive Office Building in Utulei.
>
> Department of Legal Affairs
>   Executive Office Building - 3rd floor
>   Phone: (684) 633-4163 or 633-4164
>   Fax: (684) 633-1838
>
> Immigration Office
>   Utulei Phone: (684) 633-4203 or 633-4204
>   Tafuna Phone: (684) 699-9129
>   email address for Attorney General's Office - okboard.asag@gmail.com

Comment: "Automonous" would be a better word to describe the government of American Samoa.

Comment: @DavidRicherby could be... but then the Samoans think of it as independent :-) so I was being sensitive and respectful of that.

Comment: Note that American Samoa and Samoa (formerly Western Samoa) are different. "Samoan government" would probably refer to the latter.

Comment: @user102008 thx; I edited accordingly to avoid any confusion.